# Laravel-5 cannot pass variable in create method

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel. I am trying this which does not seem to work

```
$apartment = new Apartment;
$apartment->update($apartment_input);//$apartment_input is an array
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "does not seem to work"? Is there an error message you can share?

Comment: Please share errors if any while executing this code

Comment: The value is null. >>> $apartment->update($apartment_input);
=> 0

Comment: @Sanjoy Have you set any properties to be fillable in your `Apartment` model? Otherwise their values won’t be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what was your goal but it looks like you probably wanted this

```php
$apartment = Apartment::create($apartment_input);
```

or

```php
$apartment = new Apartment;
$apartment->property = value;
...
$apartment->save();
```

or

```php
$apartment = new Apartment($apartment_input);
$apartment->save();
```

---

The reason why `update()` didn't work is because the row hasn't been saved yet and a PK value hasn't been assigned (if you're using auto increment  or sequence).

Comment: The first is correct. I want to create a new instance and populate it with data from the $apartment_input array

Comment: I did save() on the new instance and then did update($apartment_input) which seems to work. Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: Some of the attributes are in $apartment_input, not all. I tried>>> $apartment->App\Apartment::create($apartment_input);
PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR on line 1. So it does not work

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work. It means that you're doing something wrong. Is `$apartment_input` an assoc array with keys that correspond to proper attribute names?

Comment: yes. If I take the following sequence then it works: 1) $apartment = new Apartment; 2) $apartment->save(); 3)$apartment->update($apartment_input); The apartments table is properly populated.